# React 'Hello World' not loading

Tags: reactjs

I'm following a guide in a book about creating React apps. This is the very first example in the book and I copied it exactly as it was, but the page won't render.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title> Pro MEAN Stack </title>
        <script src=
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react.js">
        </script>
        <script src=
            "https://cdjns.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-dom.js">
        </script>
        <script src=
            "https://cdjns.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="contents"></div> <!-- this is where the component will appear -->

        <script type="text/babel">
            var contentNode = document.getElementById('content');
            var component = <h1> Hello World </h1>; // A simple JSX component
            ReactDOM.render(component, contentNode); // Render the conponent
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Here's what the console says,

```
react-dom.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
browser.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I'm not sure what to do at this point. I've never worked with React before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should update your cdn links to valid ones, use these:

   ```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
   ```
2. contents => content
3. The preferred way to use react is with some kind of module bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/). If webpack seems like a hustle you could use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to have a full react application up and running in no time. it's great.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the links to cdnjs, you misspell it. Also you are creating a div with id "content**s**", then you select an element with id "content".

Answer (score 0):

The following example works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>ReactJS Hello World</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src=
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.25.0/babel.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content"></div>

        <script type="text/babel">
            var contentNode = document.getElementById('content');
            var component = <h1> Hello World </h1>; // A simple JSX component
            ReactDOM.render(component, contentNode); // Render the conponent
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**References**

- [Getting started with React the easy way | CodeUtopia](https://codeutopia.net/blog/2016/01/10/getting-started-with-react-the-easy-way/)
- [React without build steps - Babel Standalone](http://www.browniesblog.com/A55CBC/blog.nsf/dx/react-without-build.html?opendocument&comments)
- [Actualize | Anyone Can Learn To Code](http://anyonecanlearntocode.com/blog_posts/why-vue-not-react-is-the-new-jquery)